# Checkbox not maintaining the state on F5

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, checkbox

I am using the checkbox in the silverlight datagrid's TemplateColumn header. By default it is unchecked. If i checked it and click on F5 in IE, it again goes to default state(unchecked). How to get it solved?

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style xmlns:dataprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data" 
                            TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <CheckBox x:Name="SubscribeAll" Content="Subscribe" Checked="SubscribeAll_Checked" Unchecked="SubscribeAll_Unchecked"></CheckBox>                                               
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: When you press F5 you are reloading the entire silverlight application, if you want to save the state, you need to save it on isolated storage (see Uladzimir answer) or server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your check box state or even form data at client side using [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx).

[There is a sample.](http://programming4.us/multimedia/882.aspx)